# How is the LOOKUP function named in German?

Tags: language, openoffice, openoffice-calc

The english version of OpenOffice Calc does have the function `LOOKUP`.

How is this function named in German (Deutsch)?

Comment: Excuse me, there are about 100 mio German speakers (Germany, Austria and part of Switzerland). Nothing to sneeze at!

Answer (score 1):

The [`LOOKUP` function](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_LOOKUP_function) is named [`VERWEIS` in German](http://www.ooowiki.de/CalcFunktionenTabellen/DatenFinden#Von_einander_unabh.2BAOQ-ngige_Zellbereiche:_VERWEIS).

A translation-table in German language is available here:

- [Übersetzungstabellen deutsch-englisch für Calc-Funktionen](http://www.ooowiki.de/DeutschEnglischCalcFunktionen)